# slowing down a user's ability to button mash in Android

Tags: android, performance, onclicklistener

I have an activity that runs some ASCII control over a network port to a remote device.
Every single button push on the interface will trigger an AsyncTask to handle the communication, and (finally) works great.
However, if a user starts button mashing like a chimp on crack, the system will crash with way too many calls on the same socket, so I've come up with a little timer function to slow down the reaction to their excitement.

I'm wondering if somebody has come up with a better way to do this?

First off, inside the onCreate:

```
btn_pwrtoggle = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pwr_btn);
    btn_pwrtoggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!buttonMasher){
                if(powerstat.equals("OFF")){
                    String[] commandToSend = {"POWER","ON"} 
                }else{
                    String[] commandToSend = {"POWER","OFF"};
                }
                deviceControl(commandToSend);
                }
                startButtonMashTimer();
            }else{
                Log.w("button masher","slow down there, monkey.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Then, in the actual Activity:

```
    Timer buttonTimer;
TimerTask buttonMonitorThread;
int chimpCrackCounter;
protected void startButtonMashTimer() {
    chimpCrackCounter = 0;
    buttonTimer = new Timer();
    buttonMonitorThread = new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            buttonMasher = true;
            if(chimpCrackCounter == 1){
                buttonMasher = false;
                buttonTimer.cancel();
            }
            chimpCrackCounter++;
        }
    };
    buttonTimer.schedule(buttonMonitorThread, 0, 500);
}
```

It seems to be working just fine, (and may help somebody having the same difficulty) but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to prevent a user from pushing a button too often is to save the time when a button was pushed, and then next time compare the last time with the current time and if the difference is too small, ignore the action.

```
final static long minTimeBetweenClicks = 1000;

long lastTime;
onClick(View v){
if( System.currentTimeMillis() < lastTime + minTimeBetweenClicks ) return;
//Handle the click
lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

The beauty of this is that it doesn't require any new threads or timers, and your AsyncTasks won't have to know about the buttons.

Comment: I'd vote that sucker up, but I don't have the rep points.
Thanks!  Nails it.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the `Button` after a click (`setEnabled(false`), perhaps in `onPreExecute`, and enable after the task is done, in `onPostExecute`.

Also, be sure to pay attention to lifecycle changes. Your `AsyncTask` may be killed if the `Activity` is paused, so be sure to check the state in `onResume`.

Comment: there's a lot of buttons on the interface, and they maybe zigging and zagging all over the screen with their happy little fingers.
With a simple timer like this running, and throwing the check into _any_ of the onClickListeners, I don't really have to track the button's enabled/disabled state within the AsyncTask -- which I like.  And I'd like to allow the user to continue to believe that the interface is working -- while handling their freakout under the hood.

Comment: Your timer method confuses me. One would typically show a progress bar or spinner to indicate work being done. You could even dynamically change the button's text to "Loading..." while the task is running. I'm not sure that "tracking" the button state is too difficult. (eg. `isEnabled()`)

Comment: That confusion makes sense on the surface, but the reality is the background process is happening SO fast, that there's no way a human would be able to see any attempts at showing a progress bar or spinner for the split second that it takes for the AsyncTask to run.

It's seriously about 300-600 milliseconds.  Too fast for their poor human brain to react, but not too fast for their caffienated chimp finger to hammer like a woodpecker on the button in the meantime.

Comment: Ohh, I see. You can accept the answer above by clicking on the check button (to the left of it). No reputation needed for that.